# asociaciones con anotaciones en MyBatis

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

Buen día familia, tengo un proyecto rest montado en Spring. Tengo un endpoind que me funciona y me retorna un array de objetos:

```
[
  {
    "accountBankId": "24083410-1d00-43a9-9a14-09bd865a1381",
    "accountId": 1,
    "accountName": "Banco de Oriente",
    "bankId": 2,
    .
    .
    .
  },
  {
    "accountBankId": "98ec6daf-0736-4e80-a9aa-0a0a8df59c78",
    "accountId": 1,
    "accountName": "Nombre Cuenta",
    "bankId": 3,
    .
    .
    .
  }
]
```

Sin embargo ahora tengo la necesidad de devolver el mismo objeto pero con un objeto dentro en uno de sus campos así:

```
{
  "accountBankId": "98ec6daf-0736-4e80-a9aa-0a0a8df59c78",
  "accountId": 1,
  "accountName": "Nombre Cuenta",
  "bank": {
    "name":"...",
    "address": "Avenida Siempreviva ..."
  },
  .
  .
  .
}
```

En este caso se remplazo bankId por bank

> **El código...**

El mapper principal:

```
public interface AsobancariaMapper {
final static String GET_ASOBANCARIA_ACCOUNTS = "select aso.nombre_cuenta, aso.datos_bancarios_asobancaria_id, aso.cuenta_id, aso.banco_id, aso.tipo_cuenta, "
        + " aso.numero_cuenta, aso.codigos_servicio_pse, aso.fecha_creacion, aso.fecha_ultima_actualizacion, aso.medio_pago, "
    + " aso.sesion_modificacion_id, aso.usuario_modificacion_id "
    + " from pps.cuenta c "
    + " left join pps.datos_bancarios_asobancaria aso on c.cuenta_id=aso.cuenta_id "
    + " where c.cuenta_id is not null "
    + " and c.cuenta_id = #{accountId} ";

  @Select(GET_ASOBANCARIA_ACCOUNTS)
    @Results(value = {
            @Result(property = "accountName", javaType = String.class, column = "nombre_cuenta"),           
            @Result(property = "accountBankId", javaType = String.class, column = "datos_bancarios_asobancaria_id"),
            @Result(property = "accountId", javaType = Integer.class, column = "cuenta_id"),
            @Result(property = "bank", javaType=BankFull.class,  column="banco_id", one=@One(select="com.payulatam.ppp4.secure.api.mappers.BankMapper.getBankFull")),
            @Result(property = "accountType", javaType = String.class, column = "tipo_cuenta"),
            @Result(property = "accountNumber", javaType = String.class, column = "numero_cuenta"),
            @Result(property = "pseServiceCodes", javaType = String.class, column = "codigos_servicio_pse"),
            @Result(property = "creationDate", javaType = Date.class, column = "fecha_creacion"),
            @Result(property = "lastUpdatedDate", javaType = Date.class, column = "fecha_ultima_actualizacion"),
            @Result(property = "lastUpdateSession", javaType = String.class, column = "sesion_modificacion_id"),
            @Result(property = "lastUpdateUser", javaType = Integer.class, column = "usuario_modificacion_id"),
            @Result(property = "paymentMethodMain", javaType = String.class, column = "medio_pago") 
    })
    public List<AccountAsobancariaBank> getAccounts(@Param("accountId") final Integer accountId) throws Exception;
  }
```

El mapper del objeto que debe estar incluido en el anterior (**getBankFull**)

```
public interface BankMapper {

    public static final String ALL_BANKS = "select banco_id, descripcion, pais_iso_3166 from pps.banco";    

    @Select(GET_BANKFULL_BY_ID)
    @Results(value ={
            @Result(property = "bankId", javaType = Integer.class, column = "banco_id"),
            @Result(property = "accountId", javaType = Integer.class, column = "cuenta_id"),
            @Result(property = "altTag", javaType = String.class, column = "alt_tag"),
            @Result(property = "description", javaType = String.class, column = "descripcion"),
            @Result(property = "image1", javaType = String.class, column = "imagen_1"),
            @Result(property = "image2", javaType = String.class, column = "imagen_2"),
            @Result(property = "pseCode", javaType = String.class, column = "codigo_pse"),
            @Result(property = "bankCountryCode", javaType = String.class, column = "pais_iso_3166"),
            @Result(property = "enable", javaType = Boolean.class, column = "habilitado"),
            @Result(property = "monthsInterestFree", javaType = Boolean.class, column = "meses_sin_intereses"),
            @Result(property = "checkoutSvailable", javaType = Boolean.class, column = "disponible_checkout"),
            @Result(property = "bankCode", javaType = Integer.class, column = "codigo_banco"),
            @Result(property = "clasification", javaType = String.class, column = "clasificacion")
    })
    public BankFull getBankFull(Integer bankId) throws Exception;
}
```

El modelo **BankFull** es un POJO.

Comment: Podrias mostrarnos tu codigo acutal, asi sera mas facil que te podamos ayudar :)

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta para que agregues el código relevante de tu pregunta. Imagino que debes acudir a la forma en cómo quieres mapear tus objetos del resultado de la ejecución del query desde MyBatis hacia Java.

Comment: Me preocupa el alcance del código expuesto en esta pregunta. Expone parte de una arquitectura en Base de Datos de una entidad como Asobancaria (que agrupa las entidades bancarias en Colombia) no es, a mi modo de ver, nada responsable...

Answer (score 1):

Estimados, para realizar esto se puede hacer de 2 maneras en el archivo de configuracion XML.
donde incluyes las sub-clase

o en el archivo .java de la siguiente manera

```
@Select("SELECT H.getNombre  as NOMBRE, C.idLugar AS LUGAR "+
    "FROM HOLA H " +
    "INNER JOIN CHAO C ON C.ID = H.ID " +
    "WHERE H.ID= #{id}")   
  @Results({
    @Result(property = "idEvaluacion", column = "NOMBRE", javaType = HOLA.class, typeHandler = HOLA.class),
    @Result(property = "idLugar", column = "LUGAR", javaType = CHAO.class, typeHandler = IntegerTypeHandler.class),
})
```

donde javaType son objetos (`HOLA.class` y `CHAO.class`) y en typeHandler el tipo de datos (IntegerTypeHandler.class)

ahora si el objeto esta dentro de otro

en el property debes poner objeto.atributo, puedes ser varios objetos dentro de otros objetos.

ejemplo

```
property = "bank.name"
```

saludos